# std::vector operator overloads don't take constant parameters?

Tags: c++

Why do all the operator overloads on [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) take references to `std::vector` but not `const` references? They aren't modifying the vectors, so why not `const`?

Comment: They do take `const` references, C++11 §23.3.6.1. That page is simply wrong.

Comment: FYI I have fixed the page, thanks for pointing out this inconsistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operators/), they *do* take const references as arguments. According to § 23.3.6.1 of the C++ 11 standard and § 23.2.4 of the C++ 03 standard, they do as well.

Comment: Thanks, members on SO are often suggesting to stay away from cplusplus.com but in this case it appears to have the more accurate information.

Comment: @Fellowshee correct. Fortunately `cppreference.com` is a wiki and errors are usually quickly fixed.

Comment: @Fellowshee there, fixed.

Comment: @juanchopanza beautiful.

Answer (score 5):

That <strike>looks like an</strike> was an oversight on that page. From section *23.3.6.1 Class template vector overview* of the c++11 standard they all take `const&`s:

```
template <class T, class Allocator>
bool operator==(const vector<T,Allocator>& x,
                const vector<T,Allocator>& y);

template <class T, class Allocator>
bool operator< (const vector<T,Allocator>& x,
                const vector<T,Allocator>& y);

template <class T, class Allocator>
bool operator!=(const vector<T,Allocator>& x,
                const vector<T,Allocator>& y);

template <class T, class Allocator>
bool operator> (const vector<T,Allocator>& x,
                const vector<T,Allocator>& y);

template <class T, class Allocator>
bool operator>=(const vector<T,Allocator>& x,
                const vector<T,Allocator>& y);

template <class T, class Allocator>
bool operator<=(const vector<T,Allocator>& x,
                const vector<T,Allocator>& y);
```